# Can't recover variable in my PHP class

Tags: php, variables, drupal

Here is the class

```
class cwb extends SoapClient {
  protected $raw_xml;
  protected $filename;
  public $users;

  /**
   * @param mixed $entity
   */
  public function __construct($entity = '') {
    parent::__construct('http://privatesite?WSDL');
    $this->raw_xml  = $this->createXmlFile($entity->token);
    $this->filename = $this->createXmlFilename($entity->nome);
    $this->users    = $this->createUserArray();
  }

  /**
   * @return string
   */
  private function getFullPath(){
    return (string)$this->getPath() . '/' . $this->filename;
  }
}
```

When I try to access my `protected $filename` in `private function getFullPath()`, my variable is always empty, anyone knows a solution to access the content of the variable?

Comment: Maybe it is really empty? Have you tried `var_dump($this->filename);` to check that?

Comment: `var_dump($entity);`

Comment: Yes, it's empty, if I set a default value in the class definition, I can access the variable normally but if I fill the variable in constructor, the variable is empty.

Comment: Are you sure `$this->createXmlFilename($entity->nome)` is returning a non-empty string? Also are you calling `getFullPath()` before the constructor finishes (i.e within `createXmlFile`)?

Comment: Thanks @DaveChen, yes, I was calling the function in the wrong order. It's working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the load order from:

```
$this->raw_xml  = $this->createXmlFile($entity->token);
$this->filename = $this->createXmlFilename($entity->nome);
$this->users    = $this->createUserArray();
```

To:

```
$this->users    = $this->createUserArray();
$this->raw_xml  = $this->createXmlFile($entity->token);
$this->filename = $this->createXmlFilename($entity->nome);
```

Loaded the necessary elements to recover the variable in the next requisition.

Thanks to @Dave Chen to the answer.